# Null is popping up when it shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, null, return

New JavaScript coder here, self taught. Learning for fun and very confused along the way.

Anyway when I check my code on the browser, "null" comes up for "computerSelection". Here is my code:

```
    let choices = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];

    function getComputerChoice(){
    let choice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random())];
    let computerSelection = (choices[choice]);
    return computerSelection
    }
```

How do I go about doing this properly so that it works?

I tried programming it in the way I thought was correct with variables in the function and I expected it to return a choice of rock, paper or scissors. Instead, all I get is "null" :/

Comment: You have to make sure first that your random number is between 0 and array length - 1. So it is a legit index and includes all the possible scenarios (0,1 and 2 in this case).

Comment: oh! Thank you! so I came up with choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)]; but that's not right either. How do I go about programming it between 0 and array length -1?

Comment: The variable "choice" is what you should be returning. Instead you're returning the choices array with your choice as the index. In other words, you're trying to return (for example) choices["Rock"]

Comment: oh okay thank you all for being so helpful! I tried the math.random() *3 but it still turned out "null"

Comment: Tried returning the variable "choice" and it's still null, but thank you for explaining that. Its sort of starting to make sense in my brain

Answer (score 1):

You were soooo close to the solution. So in your function, you need just 2 changes.

First, you need to provide the length of the array, as math.random requires your range.

Second, you already have the randomised element at this point, not the index, so there is no need to try to use it as an index.

Im currently on my mobile so please ignore syntax issues! But something like this should work:

```
let choices = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];

function getComputerChoice(){

let choice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random()*choices.length)];

return choice;

}
```